# Make __add__ to return arithmetic mean

Tags: python

I want the **add** method of my object Foo to return averaged summation. For the summation of just two objects it is straightforward:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Foo((self.n + other.n)/2)
```

How to do this for `N>2` objects? E.g. `Foo(0) + Foo(1) + Foo(2) + Foo(3)` should return `Foo((0 + 1 + 2 + 3)/4)`, i.e. `Foo(1.5)`.

========================================

**Edit**: Here's my solution

```
class Foo():    
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self._n = n
        self._count = 1

    def __add__(self, other):
        out = Foo(self._n + other._n)
        out._count = self._count + other._count
        out.n = out.n/out._count
        return out
```

Not the best way to get the arithmetic mean, but I needed to do it in this way. Also, this demonstrates how to do special additions of user defined objects, which return a function of the total sum of the objects. E.g. make `__add__` return the square root of the sum of the objects:

```
class Bar():
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self._n = n

    def __add__(self, other):
        out = Bar(self._n + other._n)
        out.n = (out.n)**0.5
        return out
```

Comment: This sounds like a very bad idea. Besides the fact that this is impossible, it will make understanding your code awfully frustrating.

Comment: It's not nice to get downvoted without any explanation... makes you wondering what's wrong with the question or the code I posted. No one benefits from this. There was a clear task that had to be done in this particular way, albeit it looking like a "bad idea". And as I showed, it's possible to do with few lines of code that is easy to understand.

Comment: Please post your answer as an actual answer, not as an edit in the question.

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be storing in the class TWO numbers: the average value and the number of samples:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, avg, count=1):
        self.avg = avg
        self.count = count

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Foo((self.avg*self.count + other.avg*other.count)
                                        /
                            (self.count + other.count),
                   self.count + other.count)
```

Even better would be just storing the sum and compute the average only if/when requested.